# Adobe Brackets editor with meteor autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, meteor, adobe-brackets

Is there is a way to make meteor autocomplete in Adobe Brackets editor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Install ternific plugin in File > Extention Manager
- Download meteor.js file from https://github.com/slava/tern-meteor to tern's folder Brackets/extensions/user/ternific/tern/plugins
- In your Meteor project create a file .tern-project or folder with the contents similar to:

```
      {
        "libs": [
          "browser",
          "jquery",
          "underscore"
        ],
        "loadEagerly": ["*.js", "*/*.js", "*/*/*.js", "*/*/*/*.js"],
        "dontLoad": [".meteor"],
        "plugins": {
          "meteor": {}
        }
      }
```

or you can edit default .tern-project at Brackets/extensions/user/ternific/tern/

Comment: When I changed the default .tern-project, auto-completion for meteor.js worked.

Comment: FYI, it appears the plugin path is now `Brackets/extensions/user/ternific/libs/tern/plugin`, at least on macs (note missing `/libs/`

Comment: I have written a blog post with a description of adding Meteor autosuggest to Brackets. The tip here works. http://www.netsi.dk/wordpress/index.php/2015/06/17/my-brackets-just-got-meteor-autosuggest/

Comment: Anybody knows where .tern-project file is located in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Brackets is using TernJS for the autocomplete. There is a TernJS plugin to work with Meteor: https://github.com/slava/tern-meteor

You would need to find a way to tell brackets to use this plugin or contact the Brackets maintainers to do it for you.

Comment: Salava Kim are you using only Vim?  I saw your vim recommendation video,

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for anyone trying to get the Ternific Brackets extension to work on Ubuntu. Before installing the extension make sure that Brackets is started as root (i.e. run `sudo brackets` in a terminal).

This will make sure the extension is installed with the proper permissions. Once installed, exit Brackets and start it as normal and you should be good to go.